# Intent chooser dialog shows package name besides the Activity label

Tags: android, android-intent

If I send files via `Intent` to other applications, the chooser dialog on Samsung devices shows the package name of my application besides the defined `Activity` labels. On Nexus devices I only see the labels, as expected. How to fix this issue?

- On Galaxy Note 3 both, label and package name are shown (see screenshot)
- On Galaxy S3 only the package name is visible

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I got it. It happens only if you use equal labels for your `Activities`. Some devices show you the package name for better differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the application label in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:label="@string/my_app_name">
        <activity>
            ...
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```